# How can I extend a Sitecore instance to act as an OAuth server?

Tags: asp.net, oauth, sitecore, single-sign-on

We have an existing Sitecore instance. A third party is building a new web application which needs to authenticate against our Sitecore user base. We have decided the best approach is to extend the Sitecore instance to act as an OAuth server.

I've done a fair bit of research and seen a load of tutorials about how to build a custom OAuth server. However, these all seem to assume the use of the ASP.NET Identity framework whereas Sitecore still uses an extension of the older SQL Membership Provider.

I did notice Sitecore ships with the [DotNetOpenAuth](http://dotnetopenauth.net/) assembly, presumably to drive its social connectors. Has anyone used this, or similar, to allow external systems to authenticate against the Sitecore membership base? If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd be very grateful.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this question will be closed, as the answers are going to be opinion-based (in part because of how you formulated the question). But yeah, using OpenID or OAuth (see http://dotnetopenauth.net/) will probably be the way to go. You don't even have to host a button, you can automatically redirect your users to the Sitecore instance unless they're authenticated.

Comment: Yes, you're probably right about this being closed. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Updated to encourage less opinion-based responses

Comment: Yeah, I voted to reopen, but this action needs 4 more votes. I doubt this is going to happen. I'd suggest creating a new question instead.